# como imprimir mas de un mayor y menor de un arreglo en c++

Tags: c++, array

El programa funciona hasta los 3 for pero desde el cuarto empieza la búsqueda del/los menor/es y el/los mayor/es, lo cual logré, pero si es que se me repite el valor (el cual es el menor o el mayor), teniendo así 2(o más) menores o mayores solo me imprime el de mas abajo de los ingresados. Entonces la pregunta es que cambiar para que me de todos los menores y diciendo cual es cual(en el espacio de los cout). Gracias de antemano.

```
int cantidad, mayor=0, menor, i, contador=0;
cout<<"ingrese cuantos reos son"<<endl;
cin>>cantidad;
int arreglo[cantidad];
for(i=0; i<cantidad; i++){
    cout<<"ingrese los dias que le faltan al reo numero"<<" "<<i+1<<endl;
    cin>>arreglo[i];        
}
cout<<endl;
for(i=0; i<cantidad; i++){
    if(100<arreglo[i]){
        cout<<"al reo numero "<<i+1<<" le quedan mas de 100 dias"<<"("<<arreglo[i]<<")"<<endl;  
    }
}
for(i=0; i<cantidad; i++){
    if(arreglo[i]>100){
        contador=contador+1;
    }   
  }
cout<<"entonces hay un total de "<<contador<<" reo/s, los cuales aun tienen que cumplir mas de 100 dias"<<endl;
cout<<endl;
```

---

```
for(i=0; i<cantidad; i++){
    if(mayor<arreglo[i]){
        mayor=arreglo[i];
        }       
    }
cout<<"al reo numero "<<    <<" es al que le quedan mas dias "<<"("<<mayor<<")"<<endl;
menor=mayor;
cout<<endl;
for(i=0; i<cantidad; i++){
    if(menor>arreglo[i]){
        menor=arreglo[i];
    } 
}
cout<<"el reo numero "<<    <<" es al que le quedan menos dias "<<"("<<menor<<")"<<endl;
cout<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Todo este código podría hacerse en un sólo bucle. El inicial donde despues de leer ya podría estar contando el número de reos con más de cien dias, el mayor y el menor.

Así como está no es nada eficiente.

No comprendo mucho el problema, pero si lo que quieres es contar el número de ocurrencias de algún valor extremo, ya sea el mayor o el menor, entonces mejor mantén un contador para cada uno de ellos. Para todo ese proceso, ni siquiera el vector es necesario.

Algo así:

```
int n;
cout<<"ingrese cuantos reos son"<<endl;
cin>>n;  // cantidad

int menor=1000000;
int mayor = 0;
int cont_mayores = 0;
int cont_menores = 0;
int cont_mas_de_cien = 0;
int x;  // por legibilidad
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    cout<<"ingrese los dias que le faltan al reo numero"<<" "<<i+1<<endl;
    cin>>x;        
    if (x > 100) cont_mas_de_cien++;

    // analisis de mayores
    if (x >= mayor) {
        if (x==mayor) {   // siguientes ocurrencias del mayor conocido
            cont_mayores++;
        }
        else {      // nuevo mayor, primera ocurrencia
            mayor = x;
            cont_mayores = 1;
        }
    }
    // analisis de menores
    if (x <= menor) {
        if (x==menor) {   // siguientes ocurrencias del menor conocido
            cont_menores++;
        }
        else {      // nuevo menor, primera ocurrencia
            menor = x;
            cont_menores = 1;
        }
    }
}
// aqui ya puedes imprimir lo que quieras
```

Answer (score 0):

El programa, tal y como está redactado, no compilará en muchos compiladores y en otros se comportará de manera errática.

Esto se debe a que en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)<sup>1</sup> las formaciones<sup>2</sup> deben tener un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación (a no ser que sean formaciones dinámicas creadas con el operador `new`). En tu caso usas una variable para definir el tamaño:

```
int cantidad, mayor=0, menor, i, contador=0;
//  ^^^^^^^^ <--- Variable.
cout<<"ingrese cuantos reos son"<<endl;
cin>>cantidad;
//   ^^^^^^^^ <--- Recibe su valor en tiempo de ejecución.
int arreglo[cantidad];
//          ^^^^^^^^ <--- El tamaño DEBE ser conocido en tiempo de compilación.
```

Lo adecuado para este caso es que uses un `std::vector`, después puedes ordenarlo y mostrar los valores de cada extremo, para conservar el identificador de reo usa un `std::pair`:

```
int cantidad;
cout << "ingrese cuantos reos son\n";
cin >> cantidad;

std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> reos(cantidad);
int indice = 0;
for (auto &reo : reos) {
    reo.first = ++indice;
    cout << "ingrese los dias que le faltan al reo numero " << reo.first << '\n';
    cin >> reo.second;
}

std::sort(reos.begin(), reos.end(), [](const auto &a, const auto &b)
{
    return a.second < b.second;
});
```

Para mostrar los valores de cada extremo una opción sería la siguiente:

```
cout << "Los tres reos con menos tiempo son:\n";
indice = 0;
for (const auto &reo : reos)
    if (indice++ == 3)
        break;
    else
        cout << reo.first << ": " << reo.second << " dias.\n";

cout << "Los tres reos con mas tiempo son:\n";
indice = 0;
for (auto b = reos.crbegin(), e = reos.crend(); b != e && indice != 3; ++b, ++indice)
    cout << b->first << ": " << b->second << " dias.\n";
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVLbbtswDH02v4LNgNRG0qCL3S5zHH/B/mDdgywzmTBb8iR5wDD02zPKzsVFsKEvgnh0SB4eUXbdw0HK4/GD0rLpa8JCGectibaEK9Z71Sj/ewqJ5mCs8t/f8H6R9MaWAEp7bIXScQJ/IOqd0gfUoiXXCUnofL0FiAJJCu1VLTiOpOk9FgXOmGzJEcqeH41DS3w4o1/0LNCUxrKcJEI0ti06oWzBRZfIB1NCXnzmJduxodK1Ygk7fGRgbyzGovcG50zGfEhJkCVHfFvtlXWeqYvFmMUZtyobFlcr4fBnzwHhXjReaBRNKIa6b8kanIWUa0kO7l/0/VBvHCe8OZJGBydeeSb2KM@dsT4OmlYVHYKby0HhinQd7l@/xZzB9cYRxBKnYZVANE7ie8uCTvWxwGrSKgkGXob6wsPw7588Zw62pAOmqO1M@IR8/IVbG6etJ2ayALXHeOQvFrjbYRrAqOIl@xEcoMZRAM4i3tg0y6/enfUzOji@GqT8X714l/ZBdcXI4K60F7fpig2eb5l1t2N4Pj9vEofpllekWl72JJnsSfVQ3gzD2L9mOX0WK3s9Hj8@QppB9gyfNk@QPWUcPcMmg/U6hc/rDaSbNWRZBn8B)</kbd>.

---

<sup>1</sup>Y otros lenguajes parecidos.

<sup>2</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*